# IntelliJ: Dependencies in classpath but not in Fat Jar?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a Spark application (Scala) written in IntelliJ and thereby used Maven as dependency management.
My aim is to execute the application right from IntelliJ and package it into a JAR that includes *some* dependencies (using Maven obviously).
In m pom.xml I declared the dependencies I want to include in the Fat Jar without specifying a scope and the one I do not want in the Fat Jar with scope *provided*.

This packages the fat jar as I intend (the "missing" dependencies are then added to the classpath with the spark-submit script upon execution).
But when I execute the application from IntelliJ (using IntelliJ default run mechanism) it is giving me the error that certain classes cannot be found.

How can I change my pom.xml and/or IntelliJ configuration to have both working at the same time?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Would something like adding the provided libraries via Module Settings -> Dependencies -> Add Library (plus sign next to the dependency list) work for you? Or are you looking for an approach to have this completely via Maven POM?

Comment: what is fat jar plugin that you use?

Comment: @t6nn: I would like to do that all via Maven POM since I don't really want to take care of downloading/updating/managing all the dependend jars...

kuhajeyan: I am using the Maven Shade Plugin

Comment: I remember doing something like this with the maven-shade-plugin's exclude feature. First, I declared the dependency as usual in the dependencies section of the POM (compile scope). Second, when creating the fat jar, added the artifact to be excluded. Like in the [Selecting Contents for Uber JAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) example.

Comment: @t6nn Perfect - that does the trick! Thanks for your help.